# Triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

There are two Table **Table_Trigger** and **Table_Trigger1**.I have created a trigger on **Table_Trigger1**. It works perfectly.Below is my Trigger script -

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger
ON Table_Trigger1

INSTEAD OF INSERT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO Table_Trigger1(FirstName)
SELECT FirstName from INSERTED I
WHERE I.firstName in (SELECT FirstName from Table_Trigger)
```

when my where condition is true, I get a message (**1 row(s) affected**) and value save in Table.But when my where condition is false, that time I also get a message (**1 row(s) affected**) and value not save in Table.

My question is - If where condition is false and value don't save in table so why I got a (**1 row(s) affected**) message. what is meaning of this message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exact statements are you running in the two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, the "rows affected" for your original insert is ignorant of what's going on behind the scenes in your trigger. It passes one row through and considers that row "affected."

I tried to find some documentation to back this up. The closest I could come was the documentation on [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), which states:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE
>   statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the
>   command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the
>   return value includes the number of
>   rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of
>   rows affected by the trigger or
>   triggers.

Of course, the `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your trigger is suppressing the return of the number of rows affected within the trigger, so you're only seeing the result of the original insert statement.